# Exclude configured in pom.xml for jacoco and exclude files in sonar

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a Java Multi maven project and I configured Jacoco maven plugin for each submodule to exclude files I don't want coverage report for.
I though I succeeded as I don't see these files I've excluded in the html report generated by jacoco. 
I assumed these class files were excluded from the jacoco.exec files.
Now I consume these accumulated jacoco.exec files in SonarQube and I see coverage of all submodules however when I entered inside the class details I saw again the classes I defined to exclude.
So I had to define AGAIN these exclusions with sonar.exclusions property in order not to see them in sonar.

For jacoco:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*JavaProjectApiModule.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

For Sonar I configured in the parent pom.xml, in the properties secion:

```
<sonar.exclusions>
        **/JavaProjectApiAModule.java
</sonar.exclusions>
```

I thought once I exclude them using jacoco configuration, they will not be added to the jacoco.exec files and in turn will not show up in sonar..
But now it seems I will have to maintain the exclusions both for jacoco AND sonar configurations and it will be a big mess in case of classes from different modules...

Am I missing something here? Is this the way? to maintain exclusions for jacoco separated from sonar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sonar.exclusions` parameter defines which files should be ommit by the scanner. It means that those files won't be displayed in SonarQube.

Files excluded from JaCoCo reports are skipped by JaCoCo agent during tests execution.

When the scanner scans files which are not included in JaCoCo report then they are displayed in SonarQube but without code coverage information. When the scanner ignores files (their paths match `sonar.exclusions`) then they are not displayed in SonarQube - no matter if they are included in JaCoCo report or not.

Comment: Hello agabrys! Thanks for the explanation! By the way I work in SAP too :) I noticed that if I exclude file from jacoco but not from sonar I see the file with  0% coverage which reduces the overall coverage... so I guess a good practice would be to maintain one exclusion list for sonar only...

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a good practice. I think a better option is to put all files which should be ignored to a specific directory, e.g. `legacy-code`, `gen-src` etc. Due to that you can simply ignore whole files in the directory `legacy-code/**`. If you cannot change the file structure and want to keep only one list then you don't have any choice ;)

Comment: Yes, probably I don't:) Thank you so much for your help!